# Manipulate strings in a txt file with Powershell - Search for words in each line containing "." and save them in new txt file

Tags: string, powershell, text, text-files

I have a text file with different entries. I want to manipulate it to filter out always the word, containing a dot (using Powershell)

```
$file = "C:\Users\test_folder\test.txt"
Get-Content $file
```

Output:

```
Compass                      Zype.Compass                        1.1.0   thisisaword          
Pomodoro Logger              zxch3n.PomodoroLogger               0.6.3   thisisaword
......
......
......
Bla Word                     Program.Name                        1.1.1   this is another entry
```

As you can see, in all lines, the "second" "word" **contains a dot**, like "Program.Name".
I want to create a new file, which contains just those words, each line one word.

So my file should look something like:

```
Zype.Compass
zxch3n.PomodoroLogger
Program.Name
```

What I have tried so far:

```
Clear-Host

$folder = "C:\Users\test_folder"

$file = "C:\Users\test_folder\test.txt"

$content_txtfile = Get-Content $file

foreach ($line in $content_textfile)
{
    if ($line -like "*.*"){

        $line  | Out-File "$folder\test_filtered.txt"

        }
}
```

But my output is not what I want.

I hope you get what my problem is.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: 1.1.0 also contains .

Comment: Also, this looks like a fixed-width file. If you can confirm that, you can GREATLY improve code simplicity and performance.

Comment: so something like `Get-Content $file|?{$_ -match '^.+?\S\s{2,}(\w+\.\w+)'}|%{$Matches[1]}|Set-Content "$folder\test_filtered.txt"` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2) to find sub strings by RegEx pattern:

```sh
(Select-String -Path $file -Pattern '\w+\.\w+').Matches.Value |
    Set-Content "$folder\test_filtered.txt"
```

You can find an explanation and the ability to experiment with the RegEx pattern at [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/inmriJ/1).

Note that while the RegEx101 demo also shows matches for the version numbers, `Select-String` gives you only the **first match** per line (unless argument `-AllMatches` is passed).

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfect. And also thank you very much for the tip with RegEx101.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like fixed-width fields, and if so you can reduce it to this:

```
Get-Content $file |                         # Read the file
    %{ $_.Substring(29,36).Trim()} |        # Extract the column
    ?{ $_.Contains(".") } |                 # Filter for values with "."
    Set-Content "$folder\test_filtered.txt" # Write result
```

Answer (score 2):

Get-content is slow and -like is sometimes slower than -match. I prefer -match but some prefer -like.

```
$filename = "c:\path\to\file.txt"
$output = "c:\path\to\output.txt"
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename)) {
    if ($line -match "\.") {
        $line | out-file $output -append 
    }
}
```

Otherwise for a shorter option, maybe

```
$filename = "c:\path\to\file.txt"
$output = "c:\path\to\output.txt"
Get-content "c:\path\to\file.txt" | where {$_ -match "\.") | Out-file $output
```

For other match options that are for the first column, either name the column (not what you do here) or use a different search criteria
`\.` Means a period anywhere seein the whole line

If it's all periods and at the beginning you can use begining of line so..

`"^\."` Which means first character is a period.
If it's always a period before the tab maybe do an anything except tab period anything except tab or...

`"^[^\t]*\.[^\t]*"` this means at the start of the line anything except tab any quantity then a period then anything except a tab any number of times.

Comment: maybe it would be worth to clarify what makes you think `-like` is slow or furthermore, what makes you think `-match` is faster that `-like`

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/powershell-operators-like-match

Comment: There are times like wins. So I suppose testing both in your scenario is advised.